# Unity UWP Application crashes on HoloLens2 without Exception-Log

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging, uwp, hololens

After a undefined while of usage my UWP-App on HoloLens2 made with unity3d crashes. In my Application I listen to logMessages with the follwing line and write the them into a TXT-Log-File.

```
Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += HandleLog
```

The Logfile contains no Exceptions or any unexpected behaviour after the Application crashes.
**Is It possible that the line of code above does not log every exception thorwn?**  For example `Application.logMessageReceived` does not, so maybe this is the wrong approach to log exceptions. The second reason for the crashes could be a internal OS-Error, **is there a way to find out the reasons for App-Crashes on HoloLens2 via some kind of internal logFile?**

**Or is there any other reason I didn´t think about which can result in such Crashes?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `is there a way to find out the reasons for App-Crashes on HoloLens2 via some kind of internal logFile` ... yes of course! Unity creates a [Player LogFile](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) anyway! (reason why to use `Debug.Log` spare in final builds ;) ) No need to do this "manually". Make sure to fully close / terminate the app and checkout `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<productname>\TempState\UnityPlayer.log` easiest via the [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal)

Comment: I Can´t find that UserProfile-Folder. The root folder I find in DevicePortal is UserFolders, it´s selected automatic when clicking on FileExplorer. Than within that I only have "3D Objects", DevelopementFiles, Documents, Downloads, LocalAppData, Music, Pictures, PublicDocuments, Videos, for me i save the Logfile in the persistentDataPath of UWP, which is, in LocalAppData->"ProductName"-> LocalState  Please keep in mind that I need to have logs for the already built and deployed application on HoloLens, not on Desktop PC

Comment: It's preferred to collect the dump for that app crash. You can refer to the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#app-crash-dumps

And what's your Unity version?